# C# create a custom file extension and add resources to it

Tags: c#, file, compression, customization, extension-methods

Hello I am making an application that use different .wav files.

What i want is to compress those wavs into a .example file with a custom extension and them make my application use those wavs

The point for this is for creating .wav packs so when a user load the .example file it will load the .wav files compressed in the file...

So if i load the file "pack1.bmkv" it will load as i said the .wav files compressed with it.

Comment: What exactly is the question being asked here?

Comment: How to make file with a custom extension and how to compress/load resource files from it?

Comment: Did my answer solve this, or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

If this really must be a DLL, then you only need to create a new Project in VS and assign resources to it in the normal way.

However, a much better (and probably easier) way to do it, is to just use a ZIP file with a custom extension and possibly a password.